# Checking for empty values in a dynamically generated input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent element with a bunch of repeating child elements with the same class. The `border` class `div` is dynamically generated

Something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="border">
      <input type="text" class="main">
      <input type="number" class="sub">
   </div>
   <div class="border">
      <input type="text" class="main">
      <input type="number" class="sub">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a button which appends the `div` with the `border` class to the parent `wrapper` class.

I want a functionality where I check to make sure that the last `div` with `border` class has atleast one input box filled out.

Is there a way for me to select the last div with `border` class inside the `wrapper` parent so that I can check wheather  or not it has any values?

Comment: Can you post what code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `querySelectorAll` to get all divs with the class of border, and use the length of the result to get the last one. Something like this;

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.border');
let last = divs[divs.length - 1];
let inputs = last.getElementsByTagName('input');
let hasValue = false; // default this to false

for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
 // Loop through them all to check for a value. Break if you find one that does
 if(inputs[i].value !== null){
   hasValue = true;
 }
}

if(hasValue){
 // Do what you want to do if at least one has a value
}else{
  // Do what you want to do if none have a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,hope it works

```js
let all = [...document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > .border")];
all.forEach((ele, i) => {
  console.log(i)
  if (i == all.length - 1) { // checking for the last one
    [...ele.children].forEach(el => {

      if (el.value != "") { // check here if value is not empty
        console.log("value not empty")
      }

    })

  }

})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="border">
    <input type="text" class="main">
    <input type="number" class="sub">
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <input type="text" class="main">
    <input type="number" class="sub">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var borders = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].getElementsByClassName("border");
    var lastBorderIndex = borders.length - 1;
    console.log(borders[lastBorderIndex].getElementsByTagName('input'));
</script>
```

This gives you access to the input fields inside that last border div inside the wrapper div.
Now you just need to loop through the values of those input fields to check if they are empty.